# How do I change the colour of jitter dots in ggplot2 box plots according to the category/value of a third variable?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to change the colour of the jittered dots in a box plot created with ggplot2

```
    library(ggplot2) 

# create factors with value labels 
mtcars$gear <- factor(mtcars$gear,levels=c(3,4,5),
                      labels=c("3gears","4gears","5gears")) 
mtcars$am <- factor(mtcars$am,levels=c(0,1),
                    labels=c("Automatic","Manual")) 
mtcars$cyl <- factor(mtcars$cyl,levels=c(4,6,8),
                     labels=c("4cyl","6cyl","8cyl")) 

p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=gear, y=mpg)) + 
  geom_boxplot()
p + geom_jitter(shape=16, position=position_jitter(0.2), alpha=.3, colour="red")
```

with "red" replaced by the categories (or values for a continuous variable).
e.g. the following will not work because the category 'Manual' is not a colour.

```
p + geom_jitter(shape=16, position=position_jitter(0.2), alpha=.3, colour=mtcars$am)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use another `aes` inside your `geom_jitter` as follows:

```
p + geom_jitter(shape=16, position=position_jitter(0.2), alpha=.3, aes(colour=am))
```

That results in:

[image]